# `Row `1` must be array` in laravel

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to import csv file in laravel with help of maatwebsite . I have query which is bringing data from two table both have relation with each other. it is exporting only one table data when I try to fetch data of both tables it gives me an error of `Row`1`must be array`

```
$data = SaleOrder::where('id',$id)->with('customers')->get()->toArray();

    return Excel::create('Packlist Sale Order '.$id, function($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
            {




            foreach($data as $customer)
            {

              $sheet->fromArray($customer['customers']);

            }

            $sheet->fromArray($data);


            });
    })->download('xlsx');
```

I want fetch data of both tables in csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `with('customers')` which means `$data` is a multi dimensional array with customers already in it, and likely breaking `$sheet->fromArray($data);`

If you remove the `with('customers')` from your query and do this:

```
foreach($data as $salesOrder)
{
   $sheet->fromArray($salesOrder->customers()->get()->toArray());
}
```

This will load it on demand and leave it out of `$data`.

Comment: you are right but still it is not fetch data of other table .only one table at a time